# Мученик, вареник — словообразование

Tags: словообразование, морфемный-разбор

От каких слов образовались и какие суффиксы имеют слова ***мученик*, *вареник***?

Comment: От прилагательных (см. ответ Людмилы), суффиксальным способом (-ик-).

Comment: Galina Avanesova, интересно, на чём основана Ваша уверенность? Вы у слова "мученик" спросили у его происхождении? Или же просто Вам так кажется?

Answer (score 3):

Мученик - от устаревшего прилагат. мученый -муч/ен/ый.

Вареник - от варёный -вар/ён/ый

Answer (score 1):

Согласно Морфемно-орфографическому словарю Тихонова эти слова имеют следующий состав: Муч/е/ник, Вар/ен/ик

Comment: Слава, у меня нет бумажного, к сожалению. Но то относилось к словарю Ефремовой, где в одном и том же словаре(в интернете) был разнобой. А словарь Тихонова представлен на официальном сайте. Если и есть разные трактовки, то это от автора, а не ошибки.

Comment: http://udarenieru.ru/index.php?word=on

Comment: Да, у этого словаря. Я не говорил, что у Тихонова.

Comment: Слава, я удаляю свои комментарии, потому что приходит замечание от модераторов. Я говорил, что суффикс - на этом сайте, а не у Тихонова. Кстати, не могли бы сказать год издания словаря? Я обратился к модераторам того сайта, и они попросили указать год издания словаря Тихонова, поскольку сомневаются, что е  у него интерфикс. Если хотите, давайте перейдем в чат, я вам пошлю ответ модераторов того сайта.

Comment: Слава, вы мне так и не ответили. Сегодня администратор того сайта выслал мне скриншот станицы из бумажного словаря, но там нигде не указывается, что е - интерфикс. Не могли вы указать страницы, где говорится, что е - суффикс?

Comment: я ничего не считаю, а пытаюсь разобраться. зачем вы так агрессивно настроены - не пойму. У разных лингвистов разные взгляды. И это Вы прекрасно знаете!!! Все что касается этого предложения "Не могли вы указать страницы, где говорится, что е - ***суффикс***?'' - я неправильно выразился. Я хотел сказать - интерфикс. Это вас так сильно задело?

Comment: Если бы я встречал, сегодня этого разговора не было бы. Раз уж я написал админу, а он мне доказывает другое, приводя в качестве аргумента скан из бумажного словаря, я хочу ему доказать обратное, тогда и ошибку на сайте,возможно, исправят. Поэтому я вас просил указать номера страниц, где указано, что е - интерфикс. Вот и все. Спор не с вами(как вам это показалось), а с админом. Раз уж так трудно - прощу прощение.

Comment: Серж, свой ответ я изменил, добавил сканы. Надеюсь, что они Вам (и админу, с которым у Вас идёт переписка) помогут.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Надеюсь это будет исчерпывающим доводом для админа.

Comment: Серж, не поделитесь, чем завершилась Ваша переписка с админом?

Comment: Слава, я привел ему все доводы,вот что он ответил: ''ознакомление со стр. 132 фрау Ефремовой смогу себе позволить только через неделю, т.к. готовлю переезд сайта на др. сервер''. Я написал, что буду ждать ответа от него и надеюсь, что ошибка будет исправлена. Но он не ответил.

Comment: _Серж: "ознакомление со стр. 132 фрау Ефремовой смогу себе позволить только через неделю"_ === А при чём здесь это? Я привожу Вам по Вашей просьбе скан из словаря Тихонова, а Вы с админом почему-то хотите искать интерфиксы в словаре Ефремовой. ЧуднО!

Comment: Слава, не в обиду будет сказано. Почему Вы всегда все неправильно понимаете? Если внимательно прочитаете нашу переписку с админом, убедитесь, что ознакомиться хотим не мы(!!!) а он!!!

Comment: Я уже вам устал повторять:спор не с вами, а с ним.

Answer (score 1):

> вареник

По Тихонову:

***варён***(ый) -> варен-**ик**

(корень -- ***вар***, суффиксы -- ***ен*** и ***ик***)

> мученик

А вот слово ***мученик*** по Тихонову может быть образовано **двумя** способами.  См. его *"Словообразовательный словарь русского языка" (М., 1990)*:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. ***муч***ить -> муч-**е/ник**

(корень -- ***муч***, интерфикс ***е***, суффикс ***ник***)

2. ***мучен***(ый) -> мучен-**ик**

(корень -- ***муч***, суффиксы -- ***ен*** и ***ик***)

Косая черта в ***е/ник*** разделяет у Тихонова интерфикс и суффикс:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При невыделении при морфемном членении слов интерфиксов они присоединяются либо к корню [(пев-ец)](http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part2.htm#7), либо к суффиксу (пе-вец).

И потому возможно и такое членение слова ***мученик***:

***муч/еник/***

Здесь ***муч*** -- корень, ***еник*** -- суффикс.

См. у Ефремовой:

> [**-еник-**](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/136026)
>
> суффикс
>
> Словообразовательная единица, выделяющаяся в именах существительных -
>   названиях лиц, которые характеризуются действием, названным глаголами,
>   от которых соответствующие имена существительные образованы
>   *(**му́ченик**, тру́женик, учени́к и т.п.)*.
>
> Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000.

Comment: А это из бумажного словаря?

Comment: Слава,  сделайте услугу, пожалуйста. Не могли бы вы указать номера страниц этих двух словарей ( где указано слово ''мученик"), которые вы указали в своем ответе? Администратор того сайта просил указать страницы.